# Faster way to insert records using sql server and jdbc

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am running a java application in which thousands of records to be inserted from one table to another. So I am doing batch insert with 100 records each. My database is SQL Server 2014 and I am using jdbc connection. Is there a faster way that will insert these thousands of records within less time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979229/processing-millions-of-database-records-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Instead of inserting the rows using JDBC batch a faster alternative that would perform everything in the SQL Server would be to use [`INSERT INTO...SELECT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#OtherTables), which allows to select rows from one table and insert into another.

Comment: Its not just select insert. Java code comes in picture since there are some conditions to be checked . For example if my source table has country column value as 'India' my dest table has countryId column with value 1

Comment: Presumably there is table that maps `country` to `countryId`, just join in the `SELECT`? If it is impossible to perform the `INSERT` in SQL Server then can you post the JDBC code?